# How to deploy nextjs with Lerna.js project using Zeit Now integrated with Github)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lerna, vercel

When I push my Next project to GitHub, I get the following error :
**You defined 1 build that did not match any source files (please ensure they are NOT defined in .nowignore)**
and this how my now.json looks like:

`

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "packages/web-app/package.json",
      "use": "@now/next"
    }
  ],
  "build": {
    "env": {
      "SECRET": "dev-key",
      "ANOTHER_SECRET": "another-dev-key"
    }
  }
}
```

`

and Package.json file which located on the root folder contains the following :

`

```
{
  "name": "biletiniz",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
    "dev": "lerna bootstrap && lerna run dev",
    "build": "lerna bootstrap && lerna run build",
    "start": "lerna bootstrap && lerna run start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.16.4"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "LamaDabbeet",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

`
**And this the project tree:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this in Now.js V2:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "awesome-app",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "packages/next-app/package.json",
      "use": "@now/next"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/packages/next-app/$1",
      "headers": {
        "x-request-path": "$1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "env": {
    "SECRET": "dev-key",
    "ANOTHER_SECRET": "another-dev-key"
  }
}
```

Where `next-app` is your next.js app package